# median downsampling in python

Tags: python, scikit-image

I would like to downsample an image using a median filter. The `block_reduce` method in `skimage` together with `func=numpy.median` seems to be appropriate at first sight. However, I got the impression that `block_reduce` applies the `func` one axis at a time, while I would expect the median filter to be applied to the whole block at once - for nontrivial inputs the outcome is not the same.

A minimal demonstration example would be this:

```
from skimage.measure import block_reduce
import numpy as np

image = np.array([[4, 6, 6, 2],
 [6, 7, 9, 9],
 [3, 0, 9, 0],
 [0, 6, 6, 4]])

expected = np.array([[np.median(image[0:2,0:2]), np.median(image[0:2,2:4])],
            [np.median(image[2:4,0:2]), np.median(image[2:4,2:4])]])

actual = block_reduce(image, (2,2), func=np.median)

assert np.array_equal(expected, actual)
```

The last assertion fails because the median filter is not applied in the way I expected.

Can you suggest other means of downsampling an image using a median filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some *hack* which solves your specific issue.

```
def clever_func(block, axis):
    # axis unused on purpose
    if len(block.shape) == 4:
        return np.median(block, axis=[2, 3])
    else:
        return block

actual = block_reduce(image, (2,2), func=clever_func)
```

Essentially, the argument `func` to `block_reduce` will be called as `func(out, axis=-1)` in the code ([source](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/measure/block.py#L77)). Instead of calling `numpy.median`, I have hijacked this, so that median gets called with the right `axis` argument.

In your example, `block.shape` will be `(2, 2, 2, 2)` in the first call, and then `(2, 2, 2)` on the second call of `clever_func`. I am only using np.median on the first call (`if len(block.shape) == 4`), and nothing on the second call.

*This is not a pretty solution.*

Answer (score 1):

A more convenient solution is to use [`view_as_blocks()`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_blocks), which reshapes your image to introduce new axes, allowing you to address blocks via the first two axes and the pixels within each block via the last two axes.

For an image with shape `(Y, X)` which you want to split into 2x2 blocks, the blockwise view will have dimensions `(Y/2, X/2, 2, 2)`.  Once you have that view of the data, it's easy to use `np.median` to compute the median of each block:

```
In [15]: import numpy as np
    ...: from skimage.util import view_as_blocks
    ...:
    ...: image = np.array(
    ...:     [[4, 6, 6, 2],
    ...:      [6, 7, 9, 9],
    ...:      [3, 0, 9, 0],
    ...:      [0, 6, 6, 4]])
    ...:
    ...:
    ...: block_view = view_as_blocks(image, (2,2))
    ...: block_view
Out[15]:
array([[[[4, 6],
         [6, 7]],

        [[6, 2],
         [9, 9]]],


       [[[3, 0],
         [0, 6]],

        [[9, 0],
         [6, 4]]]])

In [16]: downsampled = np.median(block_view, axis=[2,3])
    ...: downsampled
Out[16]:
array([[6. , 7.5],
       [1.5, 5. ]])
```

Generalizing that into a function for ND images and (ND blocks):

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.util import view_as_blocks

def blockwise_median(a, blockshape):
    assert a.ndim == len(blockshape), \
        "blocks must have same dimensionality as the input image"
    assert not (np.array(a.shape) % blockshape).any(), \
        "blockshape must divide cleanly into the input image shape"

    block_view = view_as_blocks(a, blockshape)
    assert block_view.shape[a.ndim:] == blockshape
    block_axes = [*range(a.ndim, 2*a.ndim)]
    return np.median(block_view, axis=block_axes)
```

```
In [18]: image = np.array(
    ...:     [[4, 6, 6, 2],
    ...:      [6, 7, 9, 9],
    ...:      [3, 0, 9, 0],
    ...:      [0, 6, 6, 4]])
    ...:
    ...: blockwise_median(image, (2,2))
Out[18]:
array([[6. , 7.5],
       [1.5, 5. ]])
```